# GCC - revert Process binary to C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, reverse-engineering, reverse

I would like know if there are possible to do process revert gcc with binary code create as from source code in C , for exemple:
I used ggc for compile my code using param -o then when went to set name for binary  , I set same name ex: code.c -> code.c and overwrite my source code and don't will edit again .
this was a example for application

There are method for recovery the source code in C again ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with C or programming of any kind. It's an OS question: if I overwrite a file, can I recover it? Well, that depends on which OS you are using, but for 99% of them, the answer is no. Yet another reason programmers use Git.

Comment: It's more about reversing compilation I think.

Comment: You are essentially asking "How do I decompile a binary?" Google around and you'll see that decompilers exist, but won't give you what you are looking for: your original source code back. I hope you have backups and use version control!

Comment: Also, see this link: http://boomerang.sourceforge.net/lostsource.php

Comment: Essentially no, but it you have a build with all the debug symbols, a good decompiler may be able to make only a huge mess.

Comment: I will try see boomerang,

Comment: realy I could ask better my answer but you understood :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it will not be the code You have written.
It will be the worst code You've ever seen.

Comment: Note that 'code you have written' and worst code you've ever seen' are not mutually exclusive :)